in 24.04, sshd obscures "what" and idle time
In 23.10 mantic, when I run w(1) I see who's logged in, along with how long they've been idle and what they're currently doing, e.g.
mayo@squirtle:~ # w
 11:55:00 up 19:26,  1 user,  load average: 1.65, 1.37, 1.29
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mayo     pts/0    192.168.0.43     11:31    3.00s  0.55s  0.16s w

but in 24.04 noble, I see something... less useful.
mayo@charmander:~ # w
 11:53:34 up 2 days, 13:00,  2 users,  load average: 0.32, 0.25, 0.22
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mustard           192.168.0.81     Tue06    2days  0.00s  0.16s sshd: mustard [priv]
mayo              192.168.0.43     11:31    2days  0.00s  0.04s sshd: mayo [priv]

this new output is the same even if I run w(1) as root.  I can see this improves user privacy, especially against other users, but is there a way to return to the old behavior?  In this case, the other user is a friend and I would like to know if he's been idle for a while before I reboot (e.g. if he's active I can just wall him or wait until later etc). I suspect this is a sshd setting and not a w setting?

The same was asked a few days ago Why is the command w in Ubuntu 24.04 different than older versions. The [priv] string certainly comes from sshd, however privilege separation has been "no longer optional" since openssh 7.5p1-4 so I don't think it's that - more likely to be how w (from the procps package) traverses the process tree.

... in fact, it looks like procps has been substantially re-written to "systemd-ify" it

@steeldriver yeah this is just what I needed, thanks

Yeah I was going to post an answer but tbh I couldn't follow the new procps-ng w.c code (and documentation appears to be non-existent) - it seems like the relevant part is the find_best_proc function though. If you can explain it then please post an answer yourself!

Your first w was a local login. Your second was an ssh connection. They're diffrent.
In any case, you can lie to w, and tell it the terminal is WIDE:
COLUMNS=255 w


they're all ssh connections.  the first system is headless and has no keyboard or display attached.
here's a 24.04 system with a local login and an ssh login:
 mayo@onix:~ # w`
14:45:53 up 2 days,  7:47,  2 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.01, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mayo     tty2     -                Tue06    2days  1:39   0.09s /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu
mayo              192.168.0.43     14:44    2days  0.00s  0.01s sshd: mayo [priv]

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

well I didn't really add anything to the question, I'm pointing out that the person who answered read it incorrectly and assumed something that isn't true.
